Why is the LTspice simulation behaving differently in these identical cases?
Case 1: Capacitor initial voltage initialised using .ic command, IC not grounded.
Result: Simulation is incorrect. Initial condition not being used.

Case 2: Capacitor initial voltage initialised using spiceline in the component editor, IC not grounded.
Result: Simulation is fine.

Case 3: The capacitor initial voltage is initialised using .ic command, IC grounded.
Result: Simulation is fine.

Case 4: The capacitor initial voltage is initialised using .ic command, IC GND terminal also initialised to zero.
Result: Simulation result is fine, but running extremely slow. Why?

It looks like either we need to use the spice line to initialise the capacitor voltage or ensure the IC GND pin is grounded (at least initially)
Note:

No issue without IC being placed.
Same behaviour observed with other random ICs as well.


Little bugs. Perhaps check View Log for "Could not converge to DC with sources off!"

Dynam, If you use the UIC in the .TRAN card in case 1, to avoid permitting the ITS, you should see a difference -- and slowness. I've no idea what's in the IC model. But whatever is in there is likely a part of the issue. This is also probably why adding a ground to the IC helps out. When you see something like that, then you know that there is something going on in the IC model that you can't see that is causing some troubles.

@periblepsis: Yes, with uic command, the OUT node ramps from 0V to 200V.

Why is the initial condition still being taken as 0V?
What does ITS mean in your comment?


@Dynam It's the "initial transient solution" step. It is always performed in order to work out the DC quiescent point of the circuit before starting a run. This means it will work out the charges across capacitors before running the circuit. This makes sense for audio amplifiers, for example. The DC-blocking capacitors need to be pre-charged or else you will see the initial charging taking place early on. Most people don't care about seeing that. If you don't want the ITS then you use UIC on the .TRAN card. It will then assume zero for caps, unless stated otherwise.

@Dynam That, by itself, doesn't explain all your observations. For example, in case 1 you have given a .IC card. So with or without the UIC, it should show 200 V. And if you get rid of the LT8311, it will. That's because the ITS step obeys the .IC, then it tries to find the DC quiescent point from there. Which I think should still be 200 V, without a way for the charge to leak out. Without the ITS step, it still obeys the .IC card. But in this case it won't attempt to find the DC quiescent point. So it still should be 200 V. The LT8311 model is causing some troubles.

I thought I'd spend a little time on your question. There are a few things to know about LTspice. I don't have a fuller explanation for you. But I can say a few things that may help you in the future.
LTspice removes devices that are shorted out
LTspice's programmer, Mike, has made many significant optimization decisions in the code. One of them is that LTspice will remove from simulation any devices that are short-circuited. Let's look at a some examples to illustrate nuances around this point.
The following is a very simple circuit. Just a sinusoidal voltage source and an inductor. We expect this to work. And it does appear to do so:

But as it turns out, LTspice makes a default assumption for such inductors. It adds a very small series resistance to them. As a result, inductor \$L_1\$ is not automatically removed from the circuit due to the optimization I mentioned. It stays. The circuit simulates. Everyone is happy.
Now, while LTspice does add a small series resistance to inductors as shown above, it does not do so if you couple the inductor to another inductor, as in a transformer. In that case, LTspice refuses to automatically insert a series resistance. Let's see what happens then:

Now that there is no series resistance being automatically added to \$L_1\$, the optimization step wants to remove \$L_1\$ since it is (at AC) effectively shorted by \$V_1\$.  So an error is the result.
LTspice requires a ground
You probably already know this, but may as well document it.

However, LTspice will seem to work just fine with this:

This also works, but notice the change in voltages for the earlier floating nodes:

I'm not sure exactly how LTspice handles the case where their are floating meshes. But it appears to select one of the nodes (perhaps the least connected node, or if more than one in that set then one of them at random?) and assign it the voltage value of \$0\:\text{V}\$, arbitrarily.
(The nullspace of the transpose of the incidence matrix should only show one vector for a fully connected schematic. But for schematics with several disconnected graphs, there will be more than one vector in this nullspace. LTspice handles this, somehow and for some cases, at least.)
Towards your situation now
At this point, I think it's fair to say that LTspice won't complain about some schematics that have circuit graphs that are floating. (See above.) So when you added the LT8311, you hauled in its internal model onto the schematic. But this internal model was floating, without any connection. LTspice didn't complain. But likely selected some node within it to assign a value of \$0\:\text{V}\$, but not connected to the default \$0\:\text{V}\$ ground node and instead just a default assignment to start.
We don't know what's in that model. But, clearly, whatever is in that model causes the initial transient solution step (ITS) to find that your node voltage is initially \$0\:\text{V}\$ before starting the simulation in time:

This must be a consequence of some undocumented internal model card, within the Spice model, that we nothing about.
Let's add a different model to the schematic and see:

Well, that worked! No need to add UIC, either.
So there's something in that LT8311 model that is causing the trouble. It's very likely something that isn't documented but that causes the capacitor voltage to be set to \$0\:\text{V}\$ during the ITS step. When adding the UIC to the .TRAN card in order to abort the ITS step, you get a more expected result (if slowly.)
I think that's about all we can say. Only certain people at Linear Technology (or Mike, now working on QSPICE for a different company) would be able to track it down for you.

Looks like in Case 1 and 2, the simulation has a difficulty in finding the dc operating point ( Most likely due to floating nets in IC model). I had to abort psuedo transient analysis, which resulted in failure in finding the DC operating point. When psuedo analysis is aborted,Iam not sure what happens post that- It should have started from zero. But alas, it takes ( or converges?) component initial conditions (IC=xx) wheras global initial condition .ic =xx is neglected.
In Case3 , when the LT8311 IC is grounded, it is no more in psuedo transient analysis and hence easily finds the DC operating point corresponding to .ic command.
In Case4, again the simulation has no convergence issues. It easily computes the DC operating point with the given set of initial conditions. Post that the simulation is struggling to execute fast- I have no idea why.
